# Why am I not able to route my app using react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I started learning React and React Router by making basic application but I am getting warnings that I am not able to resolve

```
Warning 1: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string 
(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
but got: undefined.

Warning 2: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required
in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

My code :

```
index.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import routes from './routes'

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

.

```
routes.js

import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router'
import Home from './components/home';
import Login from './components/login'
const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={Home}>
     <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

  </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

.
    home.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default React.createClass({
  render(){
      return (
          <div>
              <h1>Hello From Home</h1>
          </div>);
  }
});
```

login.js

```
import React from 'react'


export default React.createClass({
  render(){
    return (<h1>Hello From Login Page</h1>);
  }
});
```

this is my

package.json

```
{
  "name": "basicapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {

    "production": "webpack -p",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "aviaTorX",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
   "react": "^15.4.2",
   "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
   "react-router": "^4.0.0"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
     "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
 }
}
```

It is giving Blank screen with warnings above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using react-router `^4.0.0`, your root component need
a `Router` element. It is seems missing from your `routes.js` file.
Your `routes.js` should look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router'
import Home from './components/home';
import Login from './components/login'
const routes = (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Home}>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your routes.js should be

```
    import React     from 'react'
    import { 
        Route,
        Router,
        IndexRoute,
        hashHistory
    }                from 'react-router'
    import Home      from './components/home';
    import Login     from './components/login'

    export const routes = () => {
        return(  
           <Router history={hashHistory}>
             <IndexRoute component={Home} />
             <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
           </Router>
        );
    };
    export default routes;
```

Comment: I changed routes.js error occured => Uncaught Error: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a class like Foo, pass React.createElement(Foo) or <Foo />.

Comment: In index.js change
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
to
ReactDOM.render(< routes />, document.getElementById('app'));

Comment: I tried using == <routes /> in ReactDom.render(). It removed the error but it's displaying blank screen. Thank You

Comment: Inspect your code in browser to find the error .. or create constructor & put console.log() with some msg in each js file to find weather the files is being called or not

Comment: all Worked correctly when I changed package.json file                                 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0-rc5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `this.props.history.push('/list/')`.
But remember that, the version of my `react-router` is `^4.2.0`.